# Links to Beall's List are broken and need to be fixed

Tags: discussion, editing, hyperlinks

Beall's List was an influential list of predatory journals, but it doesn't exist any more (and hasn't since mid January 2017).

You might already know *that*, but did you know that there are over 60 posts that link to "scholarlyoa.com" (the place where the list was hosted), a URL that now redirects to another site showing **Japanese job listings**?! These links all need to either be edited to update the links to archive.org links or to remove the references to Beall's List entirely (after all, it *is* dead).

Unfortunately, my reputation is too low for me to conveniently fix all of these posts, since each of my edits would need to be reviewed by two other users. Thus I'm asking anyone who's linked to this site to fix their posts and anyone with full editing privileges to help fix the rest. And I'm not quite sure what we should do with comments (which at this point can only be fixed by moderators or deleted).

For reference, here are some searches:

- All posts that link to the site: [url:scholarlyoa.com](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ascholarlyoa.com)
- Your posts that link to the site: [url:scholarlyoa.com user:me](https://academia.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3Ascholarlyoa.com+user%3Ame)

(Due to the way archive.org URLs work, these searches may turn up posts that only link there and not to scholarlyoa.com.)

Comment: Should we replace these links with the [online and not-entirely-sure-if-correct self-proclaimed archive](https://beallslist.weebly.com/)?

Comment: Related: [Is there a website for rating and reviewing journals openly?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/102833/14341)

Answer (score 6):

The url posted by @eykanal

https://beallslist.weebly.com/

includes the original Beall's list, and at the bottom of the page new additions. It is a reasonable replacement.

*(Among the names of these publishers, my favorite is the "WIT Press" one, that bets on confusing it with the "MIT Press" of course since a "W" is just a "M" upside down, right?)*

Some urls discussing the whole issue from various points,

https://www.nature.com/articles/544416b

https://www.the-scientist.com/opinion/opinion-we-need-a-replacement-for-bealls-list-31083

https://academicworks.cuny.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1069&context=gc_pubs

There exists also [Cabbel's blacklist](https://www2.cabells.com/about-blacklist) which is not free but for a fee,

https://scholarlykitchen.sspnet.org/2017/07/25/cabells-new-predatory-journal-blacklist-review/

Comment: I don't like links to a random blog which doesn't even warn about the actual owner, copyright owner and maintenance status until you click contact (https://beallslist.weebly.com/contact.html ). If you want to link an archived copy, use the wayback machine which is just for that.